# Can't install graphics driver on Wheezy - Using Inspiron 3537

Tags: configuration, debian, graphic-card

I've recently installed Debian Wheezy 7.5 and dual booted it with Ubuntu 14.04.
I've installed all of the drivers except the graphics driver which I've been trying to install for a couple of days.
When I first booted Wheezy I got an error message that said "GNOME 3 Failed to Load" . The GUI was loading fine but pretty basic, so I knew that this is a graphics driver issue.
I ran `lspci | grep VGA` and got this:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`
I then ran `lspci | grep Display` and got this:

`03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 6660`

I tried installing the `linux-firmware-nonfree` package but it didn't configure my graphics driver. 
My Ubuntu loads the graphics driver fine.
Is there any recommendations for the package I could install, and if I need to do any modifications to xorg.conf so I can load GNOME 3?
Could I copy the graphcis driver configurations from Ubuntu to Debian Wheezy?
My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15 3537 - Core i5 processor

Comment: I'd suggest you try a newer kernel, since this is pretty new hardware.

Comment: A new kernel is not necessary, but the relevant [Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/GraphicsCard#AMD.2FATI) may be helpful.

Comment: Can you please provide more explanation thank just the link? I've already visited this page and tried installing the AMD/ATI driver before posting the question. keep in mind that my kernel versions is `3.14-0.bpo.1-amd64`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (although mine doesn't have ATI graphics, just the Intel Haswell), and found that an upgrade to Jessie sorts out both the graphics and wifi.

To upgrade, point your sources at the testing version (Jessie) and dist-upgrade

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list{,.bak}
sed -i -e 's/ \(stable\|wheezy\)/ testing/ig' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get --download-only dist-upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

At least on mine, this 'just works', and leaves you with a beautiful Gnome 3 system. I also added

```
apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
```

Since Gnome3 is a bit 'modern' for my tastes. they coexist happily, and both are great. I think I've just kissed Ubuntu goodbye!

Answer (score 1):

Edit your sources.list :

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add the following line:

```
# Debian 7 "Wheezy"
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Save and update , then install `linux-headers` and [fglrx](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/fglrx-driver)

```
aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') fglrx-driver
```

Create a configuration file `fglrx.conf`

```
mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
`echo -e 'Section "Device"\n\tIdentifier "My GPU"\n\tDriver "fglrx"\nEndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-fglrx.conf`
```

Reboot